How to improve efficiency of key look-up in table with key IDs as columns?
I have a dataframe that indicates for each ID, the neighboring IDs. My second dataframe contains a count value for each unique ID.
The goal is to create a variable that, for each ID, is the sum of the neighbouring IDs' counts; if the count of neighbour V1 is 10, the count of V2 is 40 and V3 120, the desired output is 170 for that ID.
I created a script below that does this for me, but it is very slow. Since my actual dataset is huge (both long and wide), I would like to optimize the speed of this transformation. Is there any other way?
row_sum <- function(row) {
  row_values <- unlist(lapply(row, function(ID) df_counts$count[df_counts$ID == ID]))
  sum(row_values, na.rm=TRUE)
}

set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility

#mockup data to reproduce problem
df1 <- data.frame(ID=sort(sample(1:100)), V1_id=sample(1:100), 
                  V2_id=sample(1:100), V3_id=sample(1:100))

df_counts <- data.frame(ID=sort(sample(1:100)), 
                        count=runif(100, min=0, max=999))

sum_of_counts <- as.data.frame(apply(df1, 1, row_sum))               

Desired output:



ID
sum_of_counts




1
920


2
940




If I understand you correctly you want to add values of df_counts corresponding to the V*_ids in df1 and add them as a new column.
> transform(df1, foo=rowSums(sapply(df1[-1], \(i) df_counts[i, 'count'])))
     ID V1_id V2_id V3_id       foo
1     1     1    28     3 2832.9074
2     2    13    79    33 1452.9103
3     3    78    93    93  374.8441
4     4     5    57    84 1851.1584
5     5    73    84     9 2133.3638
6     6    55    89    54 1358.5333
7     7    16    80    10 1156.1185
8     8    90    88    71 1168.0793
9     9    43    61    92  959.9667
10   10    42    43    82 1076.2204
11   11    91    22    25 1292.1155
12   12    57    26    74 1705.8851
13   13    29    54    73 2165.5263
14   14    25    98    19  852.5623
15   15    63    96    79  750.5993
[...]

